Product of Conjugate Transpose with Itself equalling the Zero Matrix.
I am reading a linear algebra book and I am stuck on one of the questions that asks to
(a) : Find all nxn matrices with real entries such that $$ A^{T}A = 0 $$
(b) : Find all nxn matrices with complex entries such that $$ A^{*}A = 0 $$ where $$ A^{*} $$ is the conjugate transpose.
For part (a) I found that the only matrices that satisfy the condition is the zero matrix because the diagonal entry of the product must all be zero therefore $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}(A_{ki})^2 = 0 \implies A_{ki} = 0 \forall k $$
I'm struggling to generalise for part b though, I stopped at stating the solution is the set S where
S is equal to the set of all nxn matrices with complex entries such that for any given column, the sum of the modulus of each column entry is equal to zero and for 2 different columns, the sum of the products of the conjugate of the first column's entries and the second column's entries is zero.
I'm asking if there is anything further to state or is it enough. If anyone can help me out I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Hint: What are the diagonal terms when the matrix has complex entries?

For a solution see the physics forum. Also $A^*A=0$ implies $A=0$.

The duplicate shows that even  ${\rm tr}(A^*A)=0$ implies $A=0$.
